# What is the correct folder in which to store application runtime data on Windows?

Tags: windows

If I have an application that needs to store some data at runtime to the filesystem (say, something like a SQLite database or cache files), what is the *correct* folder to store it in?

On *nix it would be under `/var`, which is straightforward, but on Windows I can't seem to find a proper recommendation.

Obviously it's not `Program Files` because applications don't have write-access to there at runtime. It's also obviously not in any system folder such as `Windows`.

If it's an application that a user runs then `%APPDATA%` seems like the correct place, but what if the application is something like a service that runs as `Network Service` (e.g. an ASP.Net application running under IIS that generates files)?

Comment: Yes you are right `%AppData%` is the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in service accounts do actually have Application Data folders which you *could* use:

- `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData`
- `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData`
- `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData`

However, that would mean that the data won't be available if you change which account the service runs in, and also makes it harder for the system administrator to find.

A better choice is the Program Data folder, which in modern versions of Windows is usually found at

- `C:\ProgramData`

In .NET, you can retrieve the path to the Program Data folder using [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e.,

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

You should create a folder inside the Program Data folder with an appropriate name, e.g., the name of your application and/or company.  Depending on context, you may also need to change the permissions on your subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

which gives you the path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Temp\
```

For not temproray file you can use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Hope that's what you looking for

Comment: It's not really temporary data that I want to store.

Comment: Then you can use
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)